# How to use variable inside a selector in webdriver io

Tags: selector, webdriver-io-v4

This is my selector for selecting element from second row in a table, which is working fine and returning the element name on using getText

```
get getSecondRow() {
    return $$('#BookingsData tr:nth-child(2) td span');
  }
```

I was looking for a way to parametrize this selector to return element from any row whose number is specified.

I tried to find element in third row like

```
getAnyRow(rowCount) {
    return $$('#BookingsData tr:nth-child(${rowCount}) td span');
  }
```

where rowCount=3.
But it is not working.
Getting an error as - An invalid or illegal selector was specified.
Can anyone please help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using single quotes ', try using back ticks ` around your element #BookingsData tr:nth-child(${rowCount}) td span